# wx python as portable language

Tags: linux, windows, wxpython

I chose to learn Python as I wish to have programs running on multiple platforms. I undertake development on Ubuntu.

My program uses lots of images placed in screen locations using a GridBag Sizer. When I want to change an image at a specific location I use code along the lines of

```
def RefreshSizerCell(self, item, sizer, row, column, span, flag=wx.ALL, border=10):
  self.Freeze()
  oldItem=sizer.FindItemAtPosition((row, column))
  if (oldItem !=None) and oldItem.IsWindow():
    oldItem.GetWindow().Destroy()
  sizer.Add(item, pos=(row, column), span=span, flag=flag, border=border)
  self.Layout()
  self.Fit()
  self.Thaw()
```

On the Ubuntu machine it works like a dream, but when I run it under windows I get all sorts of issues: images remainig the background, cells moving unpredictably, screen fluttering, ...

Is the issue with wxPython on Windows (have others had success?) or is it likely to be my unrobust code?

Comment: I haven't had many issues running the same wxPython code on Windows and Ubuntu, so I can't really say what your issue is. Perhaps if you could put together a small, runnable example that demonstrated the issue, we could figure this out.

Comment: Working on it - I'll be back

Comment: Trying to upload as a new question, but whatever I try I get "Your post contains code that is not properly formatted .... " It looks fine on the preview. What's wrong?

Comment: It's probably not indented

Comment: Ok. I do ctrl-K and paste in my program copied from my ide (Kate). It looks fine in the stackoverflow preview. So I'm stuck

Comment: Ok. Result. Here is my reLoaded question [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32060635/wxpython-gives-different-results-on-windows-and-ubuntu[/link]