# wxPython gives different results on Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, wxpython

I have developed a small wxPython program that gives radically different output in Windows and Ubuntu (I am more than happy to be told I've programmed it incorrectly and I would regard that as a result- provided we can get it to work)

The program displays four shapes the right hand side. Double clicking on the right hand images moves them to the left hand side and vice versa.

Issues on Windows (see screen shots taken after the same actions in Windows and Ubuntu): The buttons don't render correctly; when I click on the cross, cicle or square they move correctly to the left of the screen, but multiple images of the triangle remain; an image appears in the top left corner

None of these issues appear in Ubuntu

[image: Ubuntu screen shot]

[image: Windows screen shot]

```
    import wx

class ImageSizer(wx.Frame):

  def __init__(self, parent, title):
    super(ImageSizer, self).__init__(parent, title=title, 
        size=(250, 200))

    self.ShapeTypes=['available','selected']
    self.MainSizer=wx.GridBagSizer()
    self.SetSizer(self.MainSizer)           

    cmdNew=wx.Button(self, label='New')
    cmdNew.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onNewClick) 

    cmdCancel=wx.Button(self, label='Cancel')
    cmdCancel.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.CancelClick)       

    self.MainSizer.Add((500,0), pos=(0,0), span=(1,2))    #dummy to position Available
    self.MainSizer.Add((0,200), pos=(1,0), span=(1,1))    #dummy to position Buttons
    self.MainSizer.Add(cmdNew, pos=(2,2), flag=wx.LEFT|wx.TOP, border=10)
    self.MainSizer.Add(cmdCancel, pos=(2,3), flag=wx.RIGHT|wx.BOTTOM|wx.TOP|wx.ALIGN_RIGHT, border=10)

    self.SetBackgroundColour((246, 244, 242))
    self.Initialise()
    self.Center()
    self.Fit()
    self.Show()

  def DisplayImages(self):
    availableSizer=ShapeSizer(self, self.AvailableShapes, self.ShapeTypes.index('available'))
    self.RefreshSizerCell(self.MainSizer, availableSizer, (1,2), (1,2))
    selectedSizer=ShapeSizer(self, self.SelectedShapes, self.ShapeTypes.index('selected'))
    self.RefreshSizerCell(self.MainSizer, selectedSizer, (1,1), (1,1))

  def Initialise(self):
    self.AvailableShapes=['square','circle','triangle','cross']
    self.SelectedShapes=[]
    self.DisplayImages()

  def RefreshSizerCell(self, sizer, item, pos, span, flag=wx.ALL, border=10):
    self.Freeze()
    oldItem=sizer.FindItemAtPosition(pos)
    if (oldItem !=None) and oldItem.IsWindow():
      oldItem.GetWindow().Destroy()
    sizer.Add(item, pos=pos, span=span, flag=flag, border=border)
    self.Layout()
    self.Thaw()

  def GetShapeName(self, event):
    imgCtrl=event.GetEventObject()
    return imgCtrl.GetName()

  def onAvailableShapeDClick(self, event):
    shape=self.GetShapeName(event)
    self.AvailableShapes.remove(shape)
    self.SelectedShapes.append(shape)
    self.DisplayImages()

  def onSelectedShapeDClick(self, event):
    shape=self.GetShapeName(event)
    self.SelectedShapes.remove(shape)
    self.AvailableShapes.append(shape)
    self.DisplayImages()

  def onNewClick(self, event):
    self.Initialise() 

  def CancelClick(self, event):
    self.Destroy()   

class ShapeSizer(wx.Panel):
  def __init__(self, frame, shapes, shapeType):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, frame, id=wx.ID_ANY)

    if shapeType==frame.ShapeTypes.index('available'):
      size=40
      action=frame.onAvailableShapeDClick
    elif shapeType==frame.ShapeTypes.index('selected'):
      size=80
      action=frame.onSelectedShapeDClick
    shapeSizer=wx.GridBagSizer()
    shapes.sort()
    for ii in range(0, len(shapes)):
      bitmap=wx.Bitmap(shapes[ii]+'.png',wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
      bitmap=self.ScaleBitmap(bitmap, size, size)
      img=wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY, bitmap, name=shapes[ii])
      img.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, action)
      shapeSizer.Add(img, pos=(0,ii), flag=wx.RIGHT, border=10)        
    self.SetSizer(shapeSizer)

  def ScaleBitmap(self, bitmap, width, height):
    image = wx.ImageFromBitmap(bitmap)
    image = image.Scale(width, height, wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH)
    result = wx.BitmapFromImage(image)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':

  app = wx.App()
  ImageSizer(None, title='Image Sizer')
  app.MainLoop()
```

[image: triangle.png]

[image: square.png]

[image: circle.png]

[image: cross.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the lines

```
self.Freeze()
```

and

```
self.Thaw()
```

in

```
RefreshSizerCell()
```

Don't seem to be of any use in Windows :(

The line

```
Self.Layout()
```

also seems to be redundant

Comment: Where I say "no use", I mean they screw it up- when I remove the lines it works perfectly, leaving them in corrupts the output

Comment: That's really odd. Good to know though.